# Regex to append comma to numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of 12,000 numbers, each six digits long preceded by a single quote.

```
'100398
'100399
'108346
'100400
'100401
'100403
'110777
```

I would like to append a comma to the end of these. Is there a regex that will work in Notepad++ which would accomplish this?
so they'd look like this:

```
'100398,
'100399,
'108346,
'100400,
'100401,
'100403,
'110777,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Regex:

```
^('\d{6})$
```

Replacements tring:

```
$1,
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bA9hW7/2)